# jquery using two conditions in if is not working?

Tags: jquery

I have an input field in form like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
```

and in jquery I want the `form input text length should not be less than 4 and more than 10.` So for that I have my code is like this. But here its not working.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var textlength = $("#name").val().length;
        if(textlength < 4 && textlength > 10) {
          alert('oops error');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

but if I am using `if(textlength < 4 ) only one condition then the given one condition is working` but when I am using two conditions then its not working? So can someone tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: You use && instead of ||, How can be both condition true at same time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check `OR` condition, the value of `textlength` cannot be less than 4 and greater than 10 at the same time

```
    if(textlength < 4 || textlength > 10) {
      alert('oops error');
    }
```